# node.js -> readdir recursive

Tags: node.js, object, node-walk

I am trying to get a nested object with all files / folders / subfolders of a given path.

I am using node-walk, which gives everything I want. I am struggling to transform the result quickly into a nested object.

Basically, I get easily an array of files:

```
['path/file1.txt', 'path/subfolder1/file2.txt', 
'path/subfolder1.file3.txt', 'path/subfolder2/file4.txt']
```

(nb: It is easy to split between path & filename)

I would like to convert it to a nested object like this:

```
[
{ id: 'file1.txt', type:'file' } , 
{ id: 'subfolder1', type: 'folder', 
    children:[ {id:'file2.txt', type:'file'}, {id:'file3.txt', type:'file'} ] },
{ id: 'subfolder2', type: 'folder', 
    children: [ {id:'file4.txt', type:'file'}] }
]
```

In the end, I would like to have more information on the files (like size, date of creation), but it would be the same idea with more properties.

Can someone help me to create this nested object ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried?  SO can help you when you get stuck, but if you haven't even made an attempt then this is not an appropriate forum for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the whole thing for you, but `path.sep` (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) will help. Heres some psuedocode:

```
function transformArray(fileArray) {
     var tree={};

     for (file in fileArray) {
          addToTree(tree,path.sep(file));
     }
     function addToTree(subTree,file) {
          if(file.length==1) {
              subTree.children.push({make your file object})
          } else {
              subTree.children.push({make your folder object});

              addToTree((select your new folder).children,file.shift());
          }
     }
     return tree;
}
```